# aws-sdk in android react native setup

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native

I came across a strange issue while using `aws-sdk` package in my app in android. We are using this in order to sign and upload pictures to S3. In iOS everything is working as expected but on android it return with this error

`[MissingRequiredParameter: Missing required key 'Bucket' in params]`

This is our setup

```
export const s3bucket = new S3({
  accessKeyId: S3_ACCESS_KEY,
  secretAccessKey: S3_SECRET_KEY,
  Bucket: 'assets',
  signatureVersion: 'v4',
});
```

Here we call the function

```
s3bucket.createBucket(e => {
  // With this setup, each time the user uploads an image, will be overwritten
  // To prevent this, use a different Key each time.
  // This won't be needed if they're uploading their avatar, hence the filename, userAvatar.js.
  const params = {
    Bucket: 'assets',
    Key: file.name, // type is not required
    Body: base64Data,
    ACL: 'public-read',
    ContentEncoding: 'base64', // required
    ContentType: contentType, // required. Notice the back ticks
  };

  s3bucket.upload(params, (err, data) => {
    console.log(err, data);
    if (err) {
      alert('We are sorry there seem to be a problem. Please try again!');
    }
    if (currentIndex === -1) {
      const newDocument = {
        path: data.Location,
        page: allDocumentPages.length + 1,
        status: '',
        id_type: allDocumentPages[0].id_type,
      };
      setAllDocumentPages([...allDocumentPages, newDocument]);
    } else {
      const documentToUpdate = allDocumentPages[currentIndex];

      documentToUpdate.path = data.Location;
      documentToUpdate.status = '';
    }
    setLoadingIndex(null);
  });
});
```

Is there anything I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the missing `'Bucket'` parameter is coming from the `createBucket` method, where its `params` object was not defined, as seen from the [S3 documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#createBucket-property). You should re-define it as such.

```
export const s3bucket = new S3({
  accessKeyId: S3_ACCESS_KEY,
  secretAccessKey: S3_SECRET_KEY,
  // Bucket: 'assets',  <-- this will be ignored while defining the S3 options.
  signatureVersion: 'v4',
});

// added a `params1` variable since `params` has been taken up.
var params1 = {
  Bucket: 'assets'
};

s3bucket.createBucket(params1, e => {
  ...
};
```